# Can I control the UI Object on the other Android App from Android App?

Tags: android

I am developing in Android. I create a **Android App-A** , and it can launch another **Android App-B** via `getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("package name of Android App-B");`.

**For example:**

When the **Android App-B** start , it has an **Button** on the `MainActivity`. And it will turn on the WiFi when Button clicked.

I want the **Android App-A** control the UI Button that on **Android App-B** after launch the **Android App-B**.

1. Is it possible to control the UI Button of **Android App-B** via **Android App-A**?
2. If Yes. How to do ? Can **Android App-A** get the Button's id ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use Service/BroadcastReceiver for it. If you want to control ui of another application directly - it's not possible

Comment: No you can't. Android work in sandbox mode. Each individual app runs in its own virtual box. You can share data using `contentProvider`, can launch other app using package manager but cannot control user behaviour on UI form one app to another. If you are developing both app you can send broadcast from one app and consume that event in other app.

Comment: @IceJOKER , You mean **App-A** send `broadcast` to **App-B** ?

Comment: @Martin , yes, U can do it something like this:
1. Run App A.

2. App A open App B.

3. App B send broadcast to App A and say "Yeah, i'm ready".

3. And now App A knew that App B ready for interact, you can send commands from A to B.

I hope i explained clearly )

Comment: If that Android App-B designed accordingly you can control. By binding extra parameters to the lunching intent. Is that App-B is designed by you or your team?

Comment: @IceJOKER , OK , I am understand!  But If the App B is download from google play that not develop by me. I can not control it , I only can launch it. Right ?

Comment: @NiroshanChandrawijayakumar If the App B is download from google play that not develop by me. I can not control it , I only can launch it. Right ?

Comment: Try using Bundle or putExtra when using Intent, and then get the Extra and do the work.

Comment: @Martin , yes, you're right

Comment: To use Bundle or putExtra you need to know the exact way and parameter names. Try referring that apps official support.

Comment: . Run App A. 2. App A open App B. 3. App B send broadcast to App A and say "Yeah, i'm ready". 3. And now App A knew that App B ready for interact, you can send commands from A to B.- have anyone done this .

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I could not write in the comment as my reputation is not enough. You can do this by passing a broadcast from **app-A** to **app-B**. when the app-B receives the intent you can just perform the operation that the button click does and then set the button clicked. Regarding the id of the button you cannot access the id of the button directly. What you can do is passing the id from **app-B** to **app-A** as broadcast and then you can proceed but it is not useful at all. Simply make a method for the tasks to be performed by the button click and call it from both onClick of the button and when the broadcast is received.

Comment: have u done this if so can u show an example code how to do this ?